# How does my GPU know what game is running?

Tags: performance

I am trying to understand how game ready drivers work. How does my gpu know what application i am running and which application to use a specific driver optimization. For example the new nvidia driver makes some improvements to devil may cry 5 . how does my gpu know that I am running DMC 5. Is there a code in that application the driver recognizes? or does it not care what application i am using and treats every application the same.

Comment: To my knowledge, NVIDIA drivers just do a string match against the file name of the running executable that's invoking the graphics API. I'm having trouble finding a specific reference to back this up for an answer though.

Comment: FWIW, Minecraft used to run as minecraft.exe, but then they changed how the game is launched so that it was javaw.exe, and they had to add in a command line option (`-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump`) so that the driver would still see "minecraft.exe" somewhere.

Comment: Thats a really good example. It just seems so labor intensive keeping up with each game and the file names for the executable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what AMD is using, but Nvidia identified games based on their executable name. In addition, for mobile chips, the driver software will look for special export symbols in binaries to determine which GPU to use in case there's no matching profile being found.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I did some research on their website but I still cant find any references so that helps a lot. I was just wondering if changing game files (mods) might effect the driver recognizing the executable.